# Extending TnsOaProviderType

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-oauth2

I am trying to implement nativescript-oauth2 with IdentityServer 4 so I am trying to implement a custom provider but I am getting a compilation error as follows:

> Property 'providerType' in type 'TnsOaProviderMyProvider' is not
>   assignable to the same property in base type 'TnsOaProvider'.   Type
>   '"MyProvider"' is not assignable to type 'TnsOaProviderType'

```
import { TnsOaProvider, TnsOaProviderOptions, OpenIdSupportFull, TnsOaProviderType } from "nativescript-oauth2/providers/providers";
import { ITnsOAuthTokenResult } from "nativescript-oauth2";

export declare type ProviderTypeMyProvider = "MyProvider";
export interface TnsOaProviderOptionsMyProvider extends TnsOaProviderMyProvider {}

export declare class TnsOaProviderMyProvider implements TnsOaProvider {
    options: TnsOaProviderOptions;
    openIdSupport: OpenIdSupportFull;
    providerType: ProviderTypeMyProvider;
    authority: string;
    tokenEndpointBase: string;
    authorizeEndpoint: string;
    tokenEndpoint: string;
    cookieDomains: string[];
    constructor(options: TnsOaProviderOptionsMyProvider);
    parseTokenResult(jsonData: any): ITnsOAuthTokenResult;
}
```

Any idea how to extend the TnsOaProviderType which is defined as follows:

```
export type TnsOaProviderType =
  | ProviderTypeFacebook
  | ProviderTypeGoogle
  | ProviderTypeMicrosoft
  | ProviderTypeLinkedIn;
```

Comment: I think this question should be closed or deleted, the author of the library fixed the issue and changed the data type of the providerType property to string

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your hierarchy.

You are extending `TnsOaProviderOptionsMyProvider` from `TnsOaProviderMyProvider` but you want to pass `TnsOaProviderOptionsMyProvider` as parameter to `TnsOaProviderMyProvider` itself?

Please double check if you have named them same by mistake.